# How can I get data from 3 Bookshelf.js models in one query

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have 3 tables: `User`, `UserDrink`, and `VenueDrink`

Here are my sample data

```
User
id | name | gender |
--------------------
1  | John | male   |
2  | Jane | female |

UserDrink
id | count | user_id | venue_drink_id
1  | 3     | 1       | 1
2  | 5     | 1       | 2
3  | 2     | 2       | 2

VenueDrink
id | name | price
1  | Beer | 50
2  | Wine | 100
```

How can I get the following return using `BookshelfJs` when I query a single `User`?

```
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"John",
  "gender":"male",
  "user_drinks":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "count":3,
      "user_id":1,
      "venue_drink":{
        "id":1,
        "name":"Beer",
        "price":50
      }
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "count":5,
      "user_id":1,
      "venue_drink":{
        "id":2,
        "name":"Wine",
        "price":100
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried several attempts but I'm new to `BookshelfJs` and unfortunately, I can only go up to `UserDrink` level using `withRelated` and `hasMany` relationship.
I can only output the following:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"John",
  "gender":"male",
  "user_drinks":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "count":3,
      "user_id":1,
      "venue_drink_id":1
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "count":5,
      "user_id":1,
      "venue_drink_id":2
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to output the details of the `venue_drink` using the `venue_drink_id`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch the desired result as follows

```
var user = db.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'users',
   hasTimestamps: false,
   drinks: function() {
     return this.hasMany(UserDrink, 'user_id');
   }
});
var UserDrink = db.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'UserDrink',
   hasTimestamps: false,

   venueDrink: function() {
     return this.belongsTo(VenueDrink, 'venue_drink_id');
   }
   userRelated : function() {
     return this.belongsTo(user,'user_id');
   }
});
var VenueDrink = db.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'VenueDrink',
   hasTimestamps: false
});
user.where({
   id: 1
}).fetchAll({
   withRelated: ['drinks.venueDrink', 'drinks.userRelated']
}).then(function(data) {
   data = data.toJSON();
   res.send(data);
});
```

Comment: So what I'm looking for is `drinks.venueDrink`! Thanks a lot man, this endend my 2 days of research. :D